# Passar variavel do PHP para função do JS para que esse devolva a outro PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá,provavelmente o titulo ficou confuso,mas vou me explicar ao máximo:tenho um projeto em que em minha página está sendo listado dados de uma tabela que possuo em meu banco,esses Dados indicam um Grupo(ex.:id do grupo=14,nome do grupo=grupo,admin do grupo=fulano),e preciso criar uma maneira de "acessar" esse grupo que contem outras informações nele.
meu problema é: fiz um select que listou os grupos,que estão na conta do admin,e preciso selecionar um,pegar seu id e repassar a outro php,para que eu possa fazer select da outra tabela que se relaciona com o id do grup.
pagina do select:

```
 <header>
<a href="group.php">grupos</a> //pagina atual
<a href="../php/unset.php">sair</a>
<a href="home.php">home</a>

</header>
<hr>
 <table class="table">
     <thead>
 <tr>
   <th scope="col">ID do Grupo</th>
   <th scope="col">Nome do Grupo</th> 
   <th scope="col">Nome do líder</th>
   <th scope="col"><a href="create_group.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Criar</button></a></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php include '../php/groups.php'?> //aqui é o php que faz o select e lista
 </tbody>
</table>
```

arquivo php do select(a conexão com o banco está feita tudo corretamente,e o $id esta setado em uma variavel global $_SESSION['id'],cortei algumas partes aqui pos o codigo é muito grande,mas essa variavel $id esta setada certinho):

```
include "conexao.php";
$sth=$pdo->prepare("SELECT team_id,team_name,user_name FROM teams JOIN users ON team_admin_id = user_id WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$sth->bindValue(":user_id",$id);
$sth->execute();

foreach ($sth as $res){
    extract($res);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><span id="id">'.$team_id.'</span></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#">'.$team_name.'</a><button id="botao" onclick="getgroupINFO('.$team_id.',"'.$team_name.'")//essa é a função do js que estou querendo executar\\">Entrar</button></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td></td>'; //aqui viria alguns icones,retirei eles por enquanto
    echo '</tr>';



}
```

as "\" só coloquei aqui para fazer observações, o que eu quero é que o php passe o $team_id e o $team_name para a função do JS,pegando o id que estiver escrito na linha da tabela que eu clicar,(ex.: cliquei no botão cujo id escrito na linha da tabela é 12 e o nome "grupo1",entao a função getgroupINFO receberia (12,"grupo1"),então começa a linguagem que sei pouco:JS(JQuery incluso).

a função getgroupINFO()  precisaria pegar os dados (citando o exemplo:getgroupINFO(12,'grupo1')) e enviá-los a outro php(chamado de group_select.php);

JS(ele foi chamado no final da pagina,logo depois do JQUERY):

```
function getgroupINFO(id,groupname) {
 var dados = new XMLHttpRequest();
   dados.open("POST", "../php/group_select.php",true);
   dados.send(id)
   dados.open("POST",".../php/group_select.php",true);
   dados.send(groupname);
}
```

lembrando que o código está "cru",não tem CSS praticamente.
me digam no que eu estou errando(uma parte de mim diz que é o JS,pois é uma linguagem que ainda estou aprendendo e tenho muito pouco conhecimento) e caso seja necessário alguma informação à mais pode pedir

Atenciosamente,
Matheus Henrique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu indicaria você instanciar o jquery no seu projeto e fazer um arquivo php retornando um json para o ajax da seguinte forma

```
<script>
window.dados = "<?=$dados?>"; //Uma forma de passar uma variável do php pro JS
</script>

var dados = $('#id/.class').val(); // caso seja um form

$.ajax({
    url: 'arquivo.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {dados: dados}
}).done(function(e) {
   console.log(e) // retorno da consulta
});
```

Espero ter ajudado um pouco se tiver alguma dúvida justifique!